# Parsing javascript before parsing HTML while web scraping?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape the table data of a website. It shows a nice table on its website but when I try to use postman to send a get request to this website, the table columns are missing(except two). when I check the exact < td > which was filled in the original html, I found that it has some javascript code. I am thinking that they must be executing that code before showing it in the page. For example, one of the  value has this.

```
if(a==1){
if(b> 2) document.write("google");
else document.write("yahoo);
}
```

But I actually want the result. I'm using node-html-parser to get the data.

Comment: https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/web-scraping-javascript/ https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-daa2027dcd3/ ...

Comment: @luk2302 I know how to web scrape. I am asking a different question.

Comment: Try [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) or use a real browser with [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

Comment: No, you are not - you are asking how to scrape a website which has javascript on it. Apparently you do not know how to do that, the two links answer that.

Comment: The question is nonsense. What does it help to just parse the JavaScript part of the page? You have to execute it.

Comment: A simple HTTP request will just return HTML code. It won't execute any JS. You need a headless browser, like Puppeteer (which is basically a wrapper that controls Chrome). This will actually load the page and all its assets (fonts, images etc) and execute the script like a "real" browser. Then you can manipulate the full generated HTML

Comment: Yes, but I can't use a browser or I'd just use their website directly. I need to get that data via web scraping

Comment: Read my comment again. This is web scraping. A headless browser is webscraping on steroids. Puppeteer runs in Node.js.

Comment: But that would require much more processing power than my laptop can handle. I don't want to run a browser everytime it gets the data. Getting html and js is easier. Can't I get the final result after everything is done? like in the original site, the table is filled, but in the http request it is empty. Is there no other way than a headless browser?

Comment: No, you need a fully functional DOM, a local / session storage and a lot of other things the website may rely on a browser providing. Only alternative: reverse-engineer their javascript such that you can just perform a single backend call that retrieves the data for the table just as their javascript does.